# QuerySyntaxException: expecting OPEN, found 'DESC' near line 1

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql, jpa-2.1

I want to implement this JPQL query using JPA:

```
String hql = "SELECT new org.plugin.service.PaymentTransactionsDeclineReasonsDTO(count(e.id) as count, e.status, e.error_class, e.error_message) " +
                " FROM " + PaymentTransactions.class.getName() + " e " + 
                " WHERE e.terminal_id = :terminal_id AND (e.createdAt > :created_at) " + 
                " AND (e.status != 'approved') " +
                " GROUP BY e.error_message " +
                " ORDER BY count DESC";
```

But I get error: `Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting OPEN, found 'DESC' near line 1, column 334 [SELECT new org.plugin.service.PaymentTransactionsDeclineReasonsDTO(count(e.id) as count, e.status, e.error_class, e.error_message)  FROM org.datalis.plugin.entity.PaymentTransactions e  WHERE e.terminal_id = :terminal_id AND (e.createdAt > :created_at)  AND (e.status != 'approved')  GROUP BY e.error_message  ORDER BY count DESC]`

What is the proper way to order by count?

Comment: Don't give a column the alias `count` because it is a keyword in SQL. Replace it by a different name, maybe `amount` or anything. Replace it in the `SELECT` block and in the `ORDER BY` clause. When reading `count`, SQL will expect an opening bracket! `count(e.id) as count` should be `count(e.id) as amount` and `ORDER BY count DESC` should then be `ORDER BY amount DESC`.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the SQL keyword `COUNT` as an alias (not even in lower case). There is no way around it, you have to use alias names that are not SQL keywords (like `SELECT`, `FROM`, `AS` and so on).

I think you should use the following query, which will at least get rid of the error you posted:

```
String hql = "SELECT "
    + "new org.plugin.service.PaymentTransactionsDeclineReasonsDTO("
    + "count(e.id) as amount, " // <--- alias name changed here
    + "e.status, "
    + "e.error_class, "
    + "e.error_message) "
    + "FROM "
    + PaymentTransactions.class.getName() + " e " 
    + "WHERE "
    + "e.terminal_id = :terminal_id "
    + "AND (e.createdAt > :created_at) "
    + "AND (e.status != 'approved') "
    + " GROUP BY e.error_message "
    + " ORDER BY amount DESC";  // <-- alias name used here
```